# Akka Port Unbinding

Tags: web-services, http, akka, apache-zookeeper, haproxy

Folks, I am currently working with an API service which is working with Akka and HA proxy for load balancing. The setup has two services running in parallel and HA proxy doing the load balancing.  The akka service (which in backend is working with Lucene) has to load new data (indices) into memory once every day because of which both services are unavailable for the duration when this refresh in underway. I made the reload sequential in the backend (using Curator for Zookeeper locking) but the Akka ports are still up because of which HA proxy still send the incoming request to the service which is refreshing at that moment. Any input on how to communicate the HA proxy that this service is unavailable at the moment would be highly appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When [you bind to the socket](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/HttpExt.html#bindAndHandle(handler:akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest,akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse,Any],interface:String,port:Int,connectionContext:akka.http.scaladsl.ConnectionContext,settings:akka.http.scaladsl.settings.ServerSettings,log:akka.event.LoggingAdapter)(implicitfm:akka.stream.Materializer):scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.Http.ServerBinding]) you get a `ServerBinding`:

```
val bindServer : () => Future[ServerBinding] = () => Http().bindAndHandle(...)
```

You can use this binding to do an unbind, but that doesn't solve the problem of timing that unbind to occur in the future.

**after pattern**

Akka has a [useful pattern called "after"](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/pattern/index.html#after[T](duration:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,using:akka.actor.Scheduler)(value:=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[T])(implicitec:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]).  It provides a `Future` that completes **after** a certain period of time.  Here we will get a `Future` after 60 minutes:

```
import akka.pattern.after
import akka.Done
import akka.actor.Scheduler
import scala.concurrent.Future.successful

val scheduler : Scheduler = ???

val bindLifespan : FiniteDuration = 60 minutes

val timerToUnbind : () => Future[Done] = 
  () => after(bindLifespan, scheduler)(successful(Done.getInstance())
```

You can use this timer to trigger an unbind:

```
val unbindFuture : Future[Done] = 
  for {
    serverBinding <- bindServer()
    _             <- timerToUnbind()
    unbindDone    <- serverBinding.unbind()
  } yield {
    unbindDone
  }
```

The `unbindFuture` will first wait for the server binding to occur, then wait for the after timer to fire, and then finally unbind the socket.

You can finally use the `unbindFuture` to signal cache refresh and another binding:

```
val refreshCache : () => Future[Done] = ???

val rebindFuture : Future[ServerBinding] = 
  for {
    unbindDone     <- unbindFuture
    cacheRefreshed <- refreshCache()
    serverBinding  <- bindServer()
  } yield serverBinding
```